# Write and extract array

Tags: php, arrays

Variable `$total` is an array().

`print_r($total)` gives:

```
Array (
    [01] => Array ( [title] => text [date] => date )
    [02] => Array ( [title] => text [date] => date )
    [03] => Array ( [title] => text [date] => date )
)
```

How to write this array to `file.txt`?

And how to call created file later, so I can work with array inside it? Like:

```
$extracred_array = file.txt;
echo $extracred_array[1][title];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to serialize it with [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function like this:

```
$serialize_array = serialize($array);
```

Now you can save the `$serialize_array` in your file. To read it back and convert to array again, use the [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function.

**Update:**

```
// write array data to file
file_put_contents('file.txt', serialize($your_array));
```

To read the file back:

```
// read array back from file
$contents = file_get_contents('file.txt');

// show the array
print_r(unserialize($contents));
```

Comment: serialize() just converts array to object?

Comment: please tell how to >>Now you can save the $serialzed_array in your file. To read it back and convert to array again, use the unserialze function.

Comment: @Ignatz: It generates a storable representation of a value, pretty ideal in your situation or when saving arrays into database.